# I made a blender cube, but the colors are grey

Tags: modeling

I made a cube and colored it green. When I made it, it looked perfect. But when blender renders it, all the colors turn gray.
[image]

The grass block looks fine, but it is not rendering correctly.

Comment: Can you show us the settings for the material you've applied to the cube? It's possible that you've given it a viewport tint, but not actually a material base color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely did not change the material's **Base Color**, but instead changed the **Viewport Display** color.

**For the green color to show up in your render you need to modify the material base color itself:**

[image: Base Color]

In order to see the material, you need to switch to LookDev mode. Not solid mode. Click on the button in the below image:

[image: Lookdev]

Hope this helps.

Comment: From the OP's screen shot, they are in SOLID mode so I think you're right. They seem  to be missing the material preview icon for some reason?

Comment: I didn't even notice that. It's definitely missing - I wonder if an add-on might be causing it. Maybe OP can clarify...

Comment: Most likely reason for not having material preview button is using the "Workbench" render engine (instead of "Eevee" or "Cycles").

Comment: @scurest That makes sense, so the missing color comes from being in "Object" color mode instead of "Material" color mode.